# Use native resolution with stadard VGA driver

Tags: windows-7, resolution, macbook-pro, nvidia-graphics-card

Can't use native NVidia driver because of this MAC hardware bug - always crashing:

http://oleb.net/blog/2012/05/15-inch-mbp-mid-2010-crashing-to-black-screen/

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088?viewlocale=en_US

Known issue, Apple replaces logic board for free. However I had no Apple service around, so had no chance to fix the problem.

Works fine only with standard Windows driver. However native monitor resolution (1440X900) is not available. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: How? And what is logic board?

Comment: That is only a possible solution if you knew which one needed to be replaced, even if you do, it would be extremely difficult to acquire. You also would have to have soldering skills.

Comment: AFAIK SVGA supports a maximum resolution of 800x600 so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: MAx resolution with VGA driver on my side is 1280x800, however not enough.

Comment: Installed 2011 year Nvidia drivers from Bootcamp 4. Works more stable, however still crashes.